# getwchar() и символ новой строки в MSVC и MinGW-w64

Tags: c, visual-c++, unicode, mingw, mingw-w64

Обнаружилось, что следующий код

```
#ifndef UNICODE
    #define UNICODE
#endif

#ifndef _UNICODE
    #define _UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>      // stdin, wprintf(), getwchar()
#include <fcntl.h>      // _O_U16TEXT
#include <io.h>         // _setmode()
#include <windows.h>    // WCHAR

int wmain()
{
    // Setting Unicode mode
    
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
    
    while(1)
    {
        WCHAR symbol = getwchar();
        wprintf(L"0x%.4X\n", symbol);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

по-разному работает при компиляции в MSVC и MinGW-w64. Если запустить программу и просто нажать Enter, в случае MSVC код сработает, как и ожидается – напечатает `0x000A` один раз. В случае же MinGW-w64 эта строка напечатается дважды, то есть на `stdin` подаются два символа новой строки.

Собственно, вопрос – с чем подобное может быть связано и как добиться одинакового поведения при компиляции разными средствами?

Информация о версии MinGW-w64: `gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

Примечание: если попробуете самостоятельно скомпилировать код с помощью MinGW-w64, не забудьте [флаг `-municode`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/).

**UPD**: В MinGW поведение такое же (если заменить `wmain()` на `main()` и `_O_U16TEXT` на `0x00020000`).

Comment: Судя по всему, загадка кроется в строках с `_setmode()`, ибо если их убрать, то с переносами строк всё будет в порядке, но нелатинские символы корректно печататься не будут

Comment: И кстати, не похоже, что [документация по Unicode](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/) в MinGW-w64 полноценна - если поменять в примере "Hello" на "Привет", то строка не напечатается (по крайней мере в моей системе)